# VBA String as Integer is always "zero"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm creating a macro which will recognize months and put first 3 letters and 2 last numbers of the year into sheet name. This is what I have created so far:

For example `Cells(9,1)` is first day of the month (01/01/2016)

```
Dim mName(13) As Integer
Dim ValDate As String
Dim years As String
Dim mcount As String

mName(1) = January
mName(2) = Febuary
```

...

```
mName(13) = December

years = Right(Year(Cells(9, 1)), 2)   '16
ValDate = mName(Month(Cells(9, 1)))   'macro says its 0, but it should be January)

mcount = Left(ValDate, 3) 

Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = ValDate & " " & years
```

Result of the macro is "0 16"
My goal is "Jan 16".

Macro works fine (no errors) but its always shows "0" when there is mName integer in ValDate string. Month function works fine with no mName.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclose the names with double-quotes.

```
Dim mName(1 To 12) As String

mName(1) = "January" '<~~~ double quotes
...
mName(12) = "December" '<~~~ 12, not 13. There are only 12 months in a year
```

Comment: month 13 is undecimember :)

Answer (score 4):

***VBA*** considers `January` as a Variant.  You have not initialized `January` so its value is **0**